# Controls and Treated Matched Comparisons Using a for Loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a dummy df with its related metafile meta_df

```
df <- data.frame(Gene=c("gene1","gene2","gene3"),
                 Co_Mark_A_Treat= c(10,11,12),
                 Co_Mark_B_Treat= c(10,11,12),
                 Co_Mark_C_Treat= c(10,11,12),
                 Co_Mark_Ctr= c(15,16,17),
                 Co_Paul_A_Treat= c(10,11,12),
                 Co_Paul_B_Treat= c(10,11,12),
                 Co_Paul_C_Treat= c(10,11,12),
                 Co_Paul_Ctr= c(15,16,17))


meta_df <- data.frame(Sample=c("Mark_A_Treat","Mark_B_Treat", "Mark_C_Treat", "Mark_Ctr"
                               ,"Paul_A_Treat","Paul_B_Treat","Paul_C_Treat", "Paul_Ctr"),
                      Name=c("Mark","Mark", "Mark", "Mark","Paul","Paul","Paul","Paul"))

row.names(meta_df) <- paste0(c("Co_Mark_A_Treat","Co_Mark_B_Treat", "Co_Mark_C_Treat", "Co_Mark_Ctr",
                               "Co_Paul_A_Treat","Co_Paul_B_Treat", "Co_Paul_C_Treat","Co_Paul_Ctr"))
```

I want to make matched comparisons between ctr and treat groups according to the name.
To do that I first retrieved  the two ctr and treat lists from the meta_df:

```
groups <- unique(meta_df$Sample)
  
groups_treat <-groups[grep("Treat",groups)]

groups_ctr <- groups[grep("Ctr",groups)]
```

And then run a for loop to get the comparisons:

```
for (j in 1:length(groups_treat)) { 
  
  for (i in 1:length(groups_ctr)){
    
    
    group1 <- groups_ctr[i]
    
    cond1 <- rownames(meta_df[grep(group1,meta_df$Sample),])
    
    
    group2 <- groups_treat[j]
    
    cond2 <- rownames(meta_df[grep(group2,meta_df$Sample),])
    
    print(paste("processing ", group1 , " versus ", group2))
    
    }}
```

This works well but I get all possible comparisons also the ones that I don't want (Mark vs Paul):

```
[1] "processing  Mark_Ctr  versus  Mark_A_Treat"
[1] "processing  Paul_Ctr  versus  Mark_A_Treat"
[1] "processing  Mark_Ctr  versus  Mark_B_Treat"
[1] "processing  Paul_Ctr  versus  Mark_B_Treat"
[1] "processing  Mark_Ctr  versus  Mark_C_Treat"
[1] "processing  Paul_Ctr  versus  Mark_C_Treat"
[1] "processing  Mark_Ctr  versus  Paul_A_Treat"
[1] "processing  Paul_Ctr  versus  Paul_A_Treat"
[1] "processing  Mark_Ctr  versus  Paul_B_Treat"
[1] "processing  Paul_Ctr  versus  Paul_B_Treat"
[1] "processing  Mark_Ctr  versus  Paul_C_Treat"
[1] "processing  Paul_Ctr  versus  Paul_C_Treat"
```

How can I manipulate the code to avoid comparison between Mark and Paul samples and get only comparisons between Mark ctr and treat and Paul ctr and treat?

Here is the outcome how it should be:

```
[1] "processing  Mark_Ctr  versus  Mark_A_Treat"
[1] "processing  Mark_Ctr  versus  Mark_B_Treat"
[1] "processing  Mark_Ctr  versus  Mark_C_Treat"
[1] "processing  Paul_Ctr  versus  Paul_A_Treat"
[1] "processing  Paul_Ctr  versus  Paul_B_Treat"
[1] "processing  Paul_Ctr  versus  Paul_C_Treat"
```

Thanks a lot for your help again.

Answer (score 1):

In R you can simplify the creation ofsuch combinations using the  `expand.grid` function.

##### Step 1

First lets define a function using  `expand.grid` to make these combinations on any column based of a pattern (default args are: "Ctr vs "Treat"):

```
make_comps <- function(col, pattern = c("Ctr","Treat")) {
 comps<- expand.grid(
    col[grep(pattern[1],col)],
    col[grep(pattern[2],col)])
 paste("processing ", comps$Var1 , " versus ", comps$Var2)
}
```

see how I used elements of your code, such as the `grep` selection and the `paste` function.

#### Step 2

Next we can simplify much of the code by splitting the meta_data based on the `Name` column "Mark" and "Paul" into a list `alist` containing two subsets:

```
alist <- split(meta_df,meta_df$Name)
```

#### Step 3:

we can now iterate over `alist` and use our function from step 1:

```
lapply(alist, function(p) make_comps(p$Sample)) |>unlist(use.names = F)

[1] "processing  Mark_Ctr  versus  Mark_A_Treat"
[2] "processing  Mark_Ctr  versus  Mark_B_Treat"
[3] "processing  Mark_Ctr  versus  Mark_C_Treat"
[4] "processing  Paul_Ctr  versus  Paul_A_Treat"
[5] "processing  Paul_Ctr  versus  Paul_B_Treat"
[6] "processing  Paul_Ctr  versus  Paul_C_Treat"
```

note: i use `unlist` in the end since `lapply` returns a list. depending on what you want to do you could also opt to use `sapply` instead of `lapply` or stack instead of `unlist` to get a dataframe instead of a list.

Answer (score 1):

You could `split` your meta frame at the names and over the sub-lists `lapply` an `mapply` with `message`s and calculations.

Hope you don't mind I extended your `df` by adding Vany to the toy matrix `counts`.

```
FUN <- \(data, meta) {
  split(meta, meta$Name) |>
    lapply(\(x) {
      tr <- grep('Treat', rownames(x), value=TRUE)
      ct <- grep('Ctr', rownames(x), value=TRUE)
      ot <- grep('Treat', x$Sample, value=TRUE)
      oc <- grep('Ctr', x$Sample, value=TRUE)
      mapply(\(tr, ot, oc) {
        message(sprintf('processing %s vs %s', oc, ot))
        ## any calculations whatsoever, e.g.:
        mean(data[, ct] - data[, tr])
      }, tr, ot, oc)
    })
}

res <- FUN(counts, meta_df)
# processing Mark_Ctr vs Mark_A_Treat
# processing Mark_Ctr vs Mark_B_Treat
# processing Mark_Ctr vs Mark_C_Treat
# processing Paul_Ctr vs Paul_A_Treat
# processing Paul_Ctr vs Paul_B_Treat
# processing Paul_Ctr vs Paul_C_Treat
# processing Vany_Ctr vs Vany_A_Treat
# processing Vany_Ctr vs Vany_B_Treat
# processing Vany_Ctr vs Vany_C_Treat
    
res
# $Mark
# Co_Mark_A_Treat Co_Mark_B_Treat Co_Mark_C_Treat 
#     4.666667     6.666667     1.000000 
# 
# $Paul
# Co_Paul_A_Treat Co_Paul_B_Treat Co_Paul_C_Treat 
#     -9.3333333   -0.6666667  -10.0000000 
# 
# $Vany
# Co_Vany_A_Treat Co_Vany_B_Treat Co_Vany_C_Treat 
#     6.000000    -5.333333     1.666667
```

Use genes as row names rather than as column, since it's of character type and different from the counts which are numbers. Then you can use numeric matrix format which is more memory efficient and fasster.

To easily convert your `df` from OP in such a matrix, do

```
counts1 <- as.matrix(`rownames<-`(df[-1], df[, 1]))
```

---

*Data:*

```
counts <- structure(c(113L, 94L, 100L, 88L, 98L, 115L, 99L, 120L, 99L, 
113L, 122L, 86L, 113L, 109L, 108L, 104L, 109L, 91L, 96L, 119L, 
117L, 103L, 103L, 96L, 82L, 90L, 104L, 107L, 110L, 93L, 92L, 
92L, 105L, 96L, 102L, 96L), dim = c(3L, 12L), dimnames = list(
    c("Gene_1", "Gene_2", "Gene_3"), c("Co_Mark_A_Treat", "Co_Mark_B_Treat", 
    "Co_Mark_C_Treat", "Co_Mark_Ctr", "Co_Paul_A_Treat", "Co_Paul_B_Treat", 
    "Co_Paul_C_Treat", "Co_Paul_Ctr", "Co_Vany_A_Treat", "Co_Vany_B_Treat", 
    "Co_Vany_C_Treat", "Co_Vany_Ctr")))

meta_df <- structure(list(Sample = c("Mark_A_Treat", "Mark_B_Treat", "Mark_C_Treat", 
"Mark_Ctr", "Paul_A_Treat", "Paul_B_Treat", "Paul_C_Treat", "Paul_Ctr", 
"Vany_A_Treat", "Vany_B_Treat", "Vany_C_Treat", "Vany_Ctr"), 
    Name = c("Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Paul", "Paul", 
    "Paul", "Paul", "Vany", "Vany", "Vany", "Vany")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Co_Mark_A_Treat", 
"Co_Mark_B_Treat", "Co_Mark_C_Treat", "Co_Mark_Ctr", "Co_Paul_A_Treat", 
"Co_Paul_B_Treat", "Co_Paul_C_Treat", "Co_Paul_Ctr", "Co_Vany_A_Treat", 
"Co_Vany_B_Treat", "Co_Vany_C_Treat", "Co_Vany_Ctr"))
```